# Why does this tokenizer return incorrect values?

Tags: java, json, regex, tokenize

When tokenising a JSON string, it returns an incorrect value, like it concatenates multiple values at once (I.e. `"username": "Azoraqua", "age": }` (It should be IDENTIFIER (2 times) and STRING_LITERAL (1 time) respectively), note that it does return the `age` number as it's own token (INTEGER_LITERAL respectively).

I've tried several ways to achieve the correct behaviour:
- Changing some Regular Expressions related to IDENTIFER and STRING_LITERAL.
- Changing some of the actual tokenising logic.

```java
private static final Set<TokenData> tokenDatas = new LinkedHashSet<>();

static {
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(,:)"), TokenType.TOKEN));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\\{)"), TokenType.BEGIN_OBJECT));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(})"), TokenType.END_OBJECT));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\\[)"), TokenType.BEGIN_ARRAY));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(])"), TokenType.END_ARRAY));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\".*\":)"), TokenType.IDENTIFIER));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\".*\")"), TokenType.STRING_LITERAL, (s) -> s.substring(1, s.length() - 1)));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^((-)?[0-9]+)"), TokenType.INTEGER_LITERAL));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^((-)?[0-9]*(\\.)[0-9]+)"), TokenType.DOUBLE_LITERAL));
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(true|false)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE), TokenType.BOOLEAN_LITERAL));
}
```

```java
@Override
public Token next() {
    str = str.trim();

    if (pushback) {
        pushback = false;
        return lastToken;
    }

    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return (lastToken = new Token(TokenType.EMPTY, ""));
    }

    for (TokenData data: tokenDatas) {
        Matcher matcher = data.pattern.matcher(str);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String token = matcher.group().trim();
            str = matcher.replaceFirst("");

            if (data.action != null) {
                token = data.action.apply(token);
            }

            return (lastToken = new Token(data.type, token));
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not parse " + str);
}
```

When the input is `{"username": "Azoraqua", "age": 21}` then the output should be:
1. BEGIN_OBJECT ( `{` )
2. IDENTIFIER ( `"username":` )
3. STRING_LITERAL ( `"Azoraqua"` )
4. TOKEN ( `,` )
5. IDENTIFIER ( `"age"` )
6. INTEGER_LITERAL ( `21` )
7. END_OBJECT ( `}` )

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely in this line:

```java
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\".*\":)"), TokenType.IDENTIFIER));
```

Regular expressions are greedy. This means that they will try to match as much as they possibly can.

So, for a string such as this:

`"username": "Azoraqua", "age": 21 }`

The `.*\":` part of regular expression will match from the u in "username" for all characters up to and including the last possible `\":` which appears just before the "space" character in front of 21.

Try making your regex non-greedy with a "?" modifier.

```java
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\".*?\":)"), TokenType.IDENTIFIER));
```

You might want to allow for optional whitespace as well

```java
    tokenDatas.add(new TokenData(Pattern.compile("^(\".*?\"\s*:)"), TokenType.IDENTIFIER));
```

You will almost certainly have a similar problem with `TokenType.STRING_LITERAL`. It is also greedy. You can fix it with the same solution, i.e. making the `.*` non-greedy.

Comment: Now, the output has changed, it's technically correct but it's not exactly how I want it to be:     
`Token {type=BEGIN_OBJECT, token='{'}`
`Token {type=STRING_LITERAL, token='"username"'}`
`Token {type=COLON, token=':'}` 
`Token {type=STRING_LITERAL, token='"Azoraqua"'}`  
`Token {type=COMMA, token=','}`
`Token {type=STRING_LITERAL, token='"age"'}`  
`Token {type=COLON, token=':'}`
`Token {type=INTEGER_LITERAL, token='21'}`
`Token {type=END_OBJECT, token='}'}`

Except it reads a little too.. literal.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that because the relevant source for the Token classes is missing. But basically your LITERAL pattern and IDENTIFIER pattern are the same. The only difference is that IDENTIFIER has a colon on the end. So, if LITERAL is tested **before** identifier, then LITERAl will match first.

Comment: If this has helped you, it would be great if you can accept the answer. You can always ask a new question (rather than update this one) with the new version of your code, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Actually, I think I am happy enough with the result, not exactly what I wanted but it does suffice my need. Thanks @GMc.